# Get the url before going back

Tags: jquery

I have this code to create a button go back in navigation:

```
$('a#button-back').click(function(e){
    parent.history.back();
    return false;
});
```

It works fine.

But I need to add an if/else condition to check if a string exist in the url to where the user will be directed. If the string exists then go to the previous page if not, then it goes 2 pages back in history.

Something like

```
$('a#button-back').click(function(e){
    if('my-string' is in 'parent.history.back()'){
      parent.history.back();
    }else{
      parent.parent.history.back();
    }
      return false;
});
```

Comment: `if (document.referrer == xxx) {} else {}`?

Comment: why the vote down? It is a script question, doesn't it? Can you explain pls?

Comment: @chefnelone Looks like someone just went over this thread and downvoted everything for no reason.

Comment: @OmriAharon I guess there are more than one person voting down everything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `document.referrer` (where the use came from):

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('my-string') !== -1) {
    // go back in history 1 step
} else { 
    // go back in history 2 steps.
}
```

If you want to go back 2 steps in history, you can do:

```
history.go(-2);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history for the manual.

Comment: document.referrer is useful to check where the user came from. But I need to check where the user is going to. I change my example function line ' if('my-string' is in 'parent.history.back()'){'

Comment: If you do `history.back()` you will end up with the same url as `document.referrer`.

Comment: ... can I print in the console the value of 'parent.history.back()' in any way before navigation to the page?

Comment: No you can't. That is a security restriction. Otherwise you would be able to see wherever your user has been. I wouldn't want that.

Comment: Ok, I almost get it workingbased in your code. But now I have problem going 2 steps in history. This is not working: 'parent.parent.history.back();' Can you correct this?

Comment: parent.history.go(-2);

Answer (score -1):

You can use `window.location` to get either `href` or `host`:

```
 if (window.location.href.indexOf('myString')) {
         .....
 }
```